# Rerun JUnit Pararmetrized Suite with Maven Integration

Tags: java, maven, junit, parameterized

I've written a test automation framework where the application under test are files. I run each file through a JUnit parametrized suite. This is done because the contents of the file are read, then each record in the file is injected into the framework to be run across the same set of tests.

Now sometimes these files are very big, and testing them as singular large file takes much more time than batching the same file into several smaller files and running them through individually.

This is all well and good, but I still have to kick off each test run manually - What I want is to create some kind of loop which runs the each file during one session and reports the accumulated results as a whole to Maven.

I've read up on it and a lot of people point to Junit core, however when I try this route, Maven only reports on the last run, and doesn't retain any information about the previous test runs. (It also has some weird quirks, such as re-running the parameterized injection method twice before injecting).

The only other thought I have had is to write a Power Shell script with runs the Maven test goal for each batched file but ideally it would be just be cleaner to have Junit take care of this in-house.

Can anybody help with a possible solution to this?

Comment: Do your company/yourself have access to e.g a CI such as jenkins or similar? then you can add a hook / configuration that handles this stuff for you :-). See e.g junit plugin for Jenkins.

Comment: @vegaasen  Ah ok, that makes sense as my next step is to create a CI server with Jenkins. I was trying to solve that problem before i got to that point but it seems the solution already exists in Jenkins! Thanks